# Error after moving entity model to a new project: type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three projects in my solution. So I moved my entity model to a separate project (class library) so it will be easily accessibly by other solutions.

However, after this moving, I get the following error upon using the `using` statement for running queries on my model:

> XXX type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to
>   'System.IDisposable'

When I look at the solutions, they say that you should reference EntityFramework in your project. So my question is, do I have to add a reference to EntityFramework for every project that uses my model?

My model already uses the EntityFramework. So when I add a reference to my model project to my projects, why is there a need to refer to EntityFramework again?

Comment: Yes you have to (_"...add a reference to Entity Framework..."_). IDisposable is implemented by base class (let's say DbContext) and C# needs that reference to _know_ about it.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thanks. I guess you can add it as the answer. Sometimes a simple yes or no is better than twisted threads of confusion. :)

Comment: there is a (somehow) similar duplicate of this (I'm just lazy to search...), different types involved but same issue

Answer (score -2):

The class in your Using statement must Inherit IDisposable

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
    {

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question _"So my question is, do I have to add a reference to EntityFramework for every project that uses my model?"_ (and answer is _yes_).